# Calling a NSManagedObject method throws EXC BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsmanagedobject

I am working with core data in my app. In that i am using below function to delete and insert data in core data database table. It works fine at first time. When i call 2nd time it throws EXC BAD ACCESS.
Can anyone help to solve this.

```
@implementation abc

@synthesize delegate;

Dynamic *dbObjDynamic;



-(void) callingcoredata:(NSInteger) family type:(NSInteger) type List:(NSString *) list
{
if ([AppManager getAppMode] == Online)
{
        statdyn = type;

         arrDyanmic= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         dbObjDynamic = [[Dynamic alloc]init];

        [dbObjDynamic DeleteRecordControlsFromTable:listtype];
}
}
```

In Dynamic.m

```
-(void)DeleteRecordControlsFromTable:(NSString *)listtype
{
NSManagedObjectContext *deleteContext = [self ManagedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Dynamic" inManagedObjectContext:deleteContext]];

NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"listType == %@", listtype];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];

NSError * error = nil;

NSArray * lookupdata = [deleteContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
for(NSManagedObject *info in lookupdata)
{
    [deleteContext deleteObject:info];
    [deleteContext save:&error];
}

}
```

It throws error at `dbObjDynamic = [[Dynamic alloc]init];`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post code of Dynamic init method?

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr -  Its just initialising the object. no source for that. Is it mandatory to add code to initialise?

Comment: If you are confident that nothing happens there, you can avoid posting it here. However, I can't see no reason than, why it fails in that point of code.

Comment: have you tried to move `Dynamic *dbObjDynamic` to where you init it?
Another thing you can try, add check `if (dbObjDynamic == nil) { dbObjDynamic = [[Dynamic alloc]init]; }` so you'll initialise it not every time

Comment: So, what are you results?

Answer (score 0):

You should alloc/init to the get instance of `Dynamic` managedObject class, Instead use this -

```
Dynamic *dbObjDynamic = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:specificIndex];
```

and also call these method to get the fetchedResults of the `Dynamic` class managedObject from the managedObjectContext

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Dynamic" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                        initWithKey:@"anyAttributeOfDynamic"
                                        ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Core data error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```